# Bash script not executing command properly when run from script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=someuser
HOSTNAMEORIP=somehostname
SCRIPT="/etc/rc.d/netif restart && /etc/rc.d/routing restart"
su -c "ssh -l ${USER} ${HOSTNAMEORIP} ${SCRIPT}" -s /bin/sh someotheruser
```

If I login to the machine and just run the `"/etc/rc.d/netif restart && /etc/rc.d/routing restart"` it works. But if i run the entire script above, i get `sh: 1: /etc/rc.d/routing: not found` as if it's not handling the script part the same. I can even use the above script without a user like this

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=someuser
HOSTNAMEORIP=somehostname
SCRIPT="/etc/rc.d/netif restart && /etc/rc.d/routing restart"
ssh -l ${USER} ${HOSTNAMEORIP} ${SCRIPT}
```

And it works but I need to use `su -c <command> -s /bin/sh user` because another application is calling the script and the user associated is the only one with ssh-key login/no password to the other machine.

How can i make `su -c "ssh -l ${USER} ${HOSTNAMEORIP} ${SCRIPT}" -s /bin/sh someotheruser` run the script properly in this use case?

Comment: I think it's running `/etc/rc.d/routing restart` on the calling machine rather than the machine you are sshing to. Try separating `SCRIPT` into two commands rather than together.

Comment: same issue with ${SCRIPT1} && ${SCRIPT2}

Comment: I mean two separate ssh commands: 
`su -c "ssh -l ${USER} ${HOSTNAMEORIP} ${SCRIPT1}" -s /bin/sh someotheruser`
`su -c "ssh -l ${USER} ${HOSTNAMEORIP} ${SCRIPT2}" -s /bin/sh someotheruser`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's just work through it. This command:

```
su -c "ssh -l ${USER} ${HOSTNAMEORIP} ${SCRIPT}" -s /bin/sh someotheruser
```

Will execute this string as a shell command:

```
ssh -l someuser somehostname /etc/rc.d/netif restart && /etc/rc.d/routing restart
```

This is clearly wrong, and will fail with the same error.

To fix it, let's fix the command and work backwards. You should be executing

```
ssh -l someuser somehostname '/etc/rc.d/netif restart && /etc/rc.d/routing restart'
```

Therefore, you can update your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=someuser
HOSTNAMEORIP=somehostname
SCRIPT="/etc/rc.d/netif restart && /etc/rc.d/routing restart"
su -c "ssh -l ${USER} ${HOSTNAMEORIP} '${SCRIPT}'" -s /bin/sh someotheruser
#                                     ^---      ^---
```

Note that this hinges on the fact that `$SCRIPT` does not contain embedded single quotes. If does or if you don't know, you can use `$(printf "%q" "$SCRIPT")` instead of `'$SCRIPT'` in the embedded string to have bash auto-escape it.

Or you can switch to `sudo`. Since it uses safe and robust `execve(2)` semantics instead of `system(3)` semantics, you wouldn't have to nest escaping:

```
sudo -u someotheruser ssh -l "$USER" "$HOSTNAMEORIP" "$SCRIPT"
```

Comment: @jtlindsey My sense was that the `ssh -t -t` would fix the issue by allowing the ssh to allocate a tty. I'll noodle on the problem further.

Comment: @Technophobe01 That won't help, since the quoting problem means `&& /etc/rc.d/routing restart` is being parsed and executed on the local computer, not passed to `ssh`.

Comment: Gordon Davisson -  Agreed. 'That other guy' provided a nice clean answer and explanation. :-)